# How can I use getSupportActionBar() is to make changes from another class

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-holo-everywhere

**UPDATE:** Edited with working code!

I have a class (`ColorChanger`) where I'm trying to change the color of the actionbars from other activities, except `getSupportActionBar()` is undefined from my `ColorChanger` class. How can I do this properly?

Working code from `ColorChanger`:

```
public void changeColor(int newColor, Context context, Activity activity) {

    this.mActivity = activity;
    Drawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(newColor);
    Drawable bottomDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.actionbar_bottom);
    LayerDrawable ld = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[] { colorDrawable,
            bottomDrawable });

    if (oldBackground == null) {

        this.mActivity.getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(ld);

    } else {

        TransitionDrawable td = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[] {
                oldBackground, ld });

        this.mActivity.getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(td);

        td.startTransition(200);

    }

    oldBackground = ld;

    this.mActivity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    this.mActivity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    currentColor = newColor;

}
```

If you need more code, just ask.

Comment: http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html - your class isn't extending a sherlock activity. There is no such method in your class.

Comment: Are you using ActionBarSherlock?

Comment: @BrianRoach the `ColorChanger` class doesn't extend anything, but I wanted to know how to use `getSupportActionBar()` from this class to make changes to the other class that does extend a sherlock activity (or just activity since I'm using holoeverywhere)
@Ahmad yes, but on the other class where I want the changes to occur

Comment: Pass an activity instance to your Colorchanger, and get the support action bar from that.

Comment: Add the activity to the ColorChanger constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getSupportActionBar() is a method from the SherlockActivity class, as you can see [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockActivity.java)

If your class is not extending SherlockActivity, you can't use that method.

To use it you have two options:

1.You can create your ColorChange class as a private class inside a class that extends SherlockActivity.

2.Pass a reference of the SherlockActivity to your ColorChange class, in the constructor for example:

```
public ColorChange(SherlockActivity cActivity){

this.callingActivity = cActivity;

}
```

And then from your method:

```
this.callingActivity.getSupportActionBar()
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This works in code, but whenever I try to run this on my device, I get an error at line 25, which is `Drawable bottomDrawable = mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar_bottom);`

Comment: Actually, I got it working, thank you! :D
I will update the OP with the working code :D